# Firestore v9 create/update subcollection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a call in firestore v9 that will create a subcollection with data if none exists, or update if it does but this does not seem to be possible. Only setDoc seems to support merge, and setDoc does not seem to support subcollections (only addDoc). Is there any way to accomplish this? And if this cannot be done directly, how can i check if a subcollection exists in v9 and update it if so?

The code below produces a typeerror on colRef, and a firebase error on execution

```
  const db = getFirestore();
  const docRef = doc(collection(db, 'Collection'), userId);
  const colRef = collection(docRef, "Subcollection");
  await setDoc(colRef, subcollectionData, { merge: true });
```

firebase error

> [Unhandled promise rejection: FirebaseError: Expected type 'Sa', but
> it was: a custom Ca object]"

Comment: Two things: 1) it's not possible to create an empty subcollection. If you want a subcollection to exist, simply create a document in it. Subcollections are not documents. 2) setDoc works just fine with documents in subcollections, just the same as top-level collections.  I suggest editing the question in more detail to explain what exactly isn't working the way you expect.  What is it doing now?  Is there an error message?

Comment: Please edit the question to answer my questions and provide more detail.  Don't leave important details in comments.

Comment: Given that you now know that subcollections are not documents and can't be created with the SDK, and subcollections work just the same as top-level collections, what are you trying to produce here?  Empty collections are not an option.  You must create a document if you want a subcollection.

Comment: you can create subcollections via sdk with v8, this is no longer possible in v9? I am passing data to populate the subcollection as well.

Comment: Maybe your question is actually about converting v8 code to v9.  In that case, show your working v8 code, explain what it does, and where your v9 code is going wrong.  v9 does not change the database works at all.  It is functionally equivalent to v8, just with different syntax.

Comment: How is your `subcollectionData` variable declared and initialized?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have the wrong syntax for `docRef`, `colRef`, and `setDoc`

If you're using that Firebase v9 it shouldn't have that `collection` because you're already referring to that collection and for the `colRef` it should be a path through your `subCollection`.

It still supports subcollections using `setDoc` you just need to configure your code to do so.

Sample code for `setDoc`:

```
const subColRef = doc(db, 'collectionName',  'documentID','subCollectionID', 'subCollectionName');
await setDoc(subColRef, subcollectionData, { merge: true });
```

Sample code for `addDoc`:

```
const subcollectionData = {test:'test'};

const subColRef = collection(db, 'collectionName',  'documentID','subCollectionID');
await addDoc(subColRef, subcollectionData, { merge: true });
```

You may refer to this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) for the syntax Web version 9 (modular).